# How to Truncate(Delete all rows) table on remote SQL server via Local Linux machine

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux

In my application(on Linux) I receive a .DAT file daily which I'm supposed to Load into a remote SQL server Table. As per requirement, I should Truncate(or Delete all rows) from this table before I load the .DAT file into the table.

I have tried below command

```
mysql -h <servername>,<port-number> -u <username> -p <password> -e "DELETE from <DB_name>.<Schema_name>.<Table_name>"
```

but it fails with error

> -ksh: mysql: not found [No such file or directory]

I reached out to a Linux expert in my team and he did a find for "mysql" and from the result he interpreted that MYSQL is not installed in the Local Linux machine.

Further I tried BCP

```
bcp "Delete from [DB_name].[schema_name].[table_name]" queryout  <output_file_full_path> -S <servername>,<port-number> -m 0 -e <error_file_full_path> -T -c -t '|'
```

which failed with below message

> Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]BCP host-files must contain
>   at least one column SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column
>   level collations

I understand BCP queryout requires some result to be stored into file but Delete does not return any thus the BCP failure.

Thus I want to know if there is any alternate to Delete data from Remote SQL Table via Local Linux machine.

Comment: So, is it SQL Server or MySQL? Those are two very different products and you can't just use whichever's tools to connect to the other. Please fix the tags. If it's MySQL why not install the client tools on that machine? Also truncating is usually faster than delete all.

Comment: Hi Sami, sorry for the mix up, edited the question. It's SQL server. So I guess I cannot use 
mysql -h <servername>,<port-number> -u <username> -p <password> -e "DELETE from <DB_name>.<Schema_name>.<Table_name>", lemme know if am wrong. Agreed Truncate is better option than delete all. Now am looking for syntax to TRUNCATE table on Remote Sql Server via local Linux machine which currently does not have MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server, I recommend you use sqlcmd/bcp + ODBC Driver.

To do so:

- Download the ODBC Driver from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339
- Download the sqlcmd/bcp tools from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591

Restart your Windows machine and connect to SQL Server using the following:

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -d Adventure_Works -U myuser -P myP@ssword -I
```

If you would like to use bcp, check out some examples here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

If you are on Linux, follow this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/02/04/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/